# On an html canvas, I am trying to draw a square at a specific point, but if the x and y aren't the same, it dilates and distorts

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, var, rect

I have messed with the variables (shifting between + and -, etc), but it always keeps dialating, whatever I do.

```js
var c = document.getElementById("mycanvas").getContext("2d");
c.fillStyle = "blue";
c.fillRect (0,0,500,350);

function square(x,y) {
    var leftX = (x - 10)
    var leftY = (y - 10)
    var rightX = (x + 10)
    var rightY = (y + 10)
    c.fillStyle = "red";
    c.fillRect (leftX,leftY,rightX,rightY)
}

square(40,20);
```

```html
<canvas id="mycanvas" width="1000" height="1000"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`fillRect`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/fillRect) function uses the parameters as follows: `void ctx.fillRect(x, y, width, height);`

So in your case you're calling the `square` function with `40` and `20` which will translate (according to your function) to the coordinates x = `30` and y = `10` with a width of `50` and a height of `30`.

```js
var c = document.getElementById("mycanvas").getContext("2d");
c.fillStyle = "blue";
c.fillRect (0,0,500,350);

function square(x,y) {
    var leftX = (x - 10); // x = 30
    var leftY = (y - 10); // y = 10
    var width = (x + 10); // width = 50
    var height = (y + 10); // height = 30
    c.fillStyle = "red";
    c.fillRect (leftX,leftY,width,height);
}

square(40,20);
```

```html
<canvas id="mycanvas" width="1000" height="1000"></canvas>
```

If you want a square you should do something like this:

```js
var c = document.getElementById("mycanvas").getContext("2d");
c.fillStyle = "blue";
c.fillRect (0,0,500,350);

function square(x,y) {
    var leftX = (x - 10); // x = 30
    var leftY = (y - 10); // y = 10
    c.fillStyle = "red";
    c.fillRect (leftX,leftY,20,20);
}

square(40,20);
```

```html
<canvas id="mycanvas" width="1000" height="1000"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks! I thought it was weird that you only had to put in coordinates for two corners.